# Creating Table w PyHive & SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive, sqlalchemy, pyhive

I'm trying to create a table in a Hive Database using SqlAlchemy ORM. My setting is Python 3.6 with `PyHive==0.6.1` and `SQLAlchemy==1.2.11` (with their relative dependencies) and `Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.15.1`.

My approach is the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

host = 'localhost'
port = 10000
database = 'foo'

engine = create_engine(f'hive://{host}:{port}')
engine.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE {database}')
engine.execute(f'USE {database}')
```

this works fine connecting to Hive and creating a new database. At this point I create the data model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

ModelBase = declarative_base()


class TestTable(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column(String(32), index=True)
```

and I try to:

```
ModelBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

with no success :( because the following exception raises:

```
OperationalError: (pyhive.exc.OperationalError) TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=3, infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:10 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'INT' in create table statement:28:27", 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:400', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:187', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:271', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:337', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:439', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:405', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:606', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63', 'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2', 'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:415', 'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1924', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59', 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28:executeStatement::-1', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:257', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:501', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1313', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1298', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745', "*org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 3:10 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'INT' in create table statement:32:5", 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:208', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:170', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:524', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileInternal:Driver.java:1358', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileAndRespond:Driver.java:1345', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:185'], sqlState='42000', errorCode=40000, errorMessage="Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:10 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'INT' in create table statement"), operationHandle=None) [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE `test_table` (\n\t`id` INT NOT NULL, \n\t`text` STRING, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n)\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

in which I think this is the relevant part:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:10 mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'INT' in create table statement"), operationHandle=None) [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE `test_table` (\n\t`id` INT NOT NULL, \n\t`text` STRING, \n\tPRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n)\n\n']
```

Here [PyHive#sqlalchemy](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#sqlalchemy) the example assume the table to be already there, but what if I need to create it?

Comment: Dear @Pierluigi , could you find the solution? As far as I search, there is no way to use SQLalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base for making query or creating table. Also, it seems PyHive is not able to create Hive table at all, it's developed to make queries.

Comment: @SeyedHasanMousavi sorry no updates on this :(

Comment: @Pierluigi Hi, I'm also dealing the same problem as you. Have you found a way to create your tables.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @DhayfOTHMEN sorry a lot of time passed :( what about the solution provided by RKB below?

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same issue with a similar error. Oddly I found that if I re-ran the cell in Jupyter the table was created in Hive.

To get rid of the error and have the code run smoothly, I added a create table statement.  The final code below ran without error. If you need to add more data you should just be able to comment out the engine.execute line.  Good luck!

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#Input Information
host = 'username@local-host'
port = 10000
schema = 'hive_schema'
table = 'new_table'

#Execution
engine = create_engine(f'hive://{host}:{port}/{schema}')
engine.execute('CREATE TABLE ' + table + ' (col1 col1-type, col2 col2-type)')
Data.to_sql(name=table, con=engine, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Not sure how it could have gone through in Jupyter either, since `NOT NULL` (the query that sqlalchemy emits) is not a valid usage in CREATE TABLE: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable